# Delete QMap value as a pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-allocation

I have a `QMap` with key `QString` and with the **value** `myClass`. I've looked through the Qt documentation and decided to define value as pointer to `myClass` object. But, I'm puzzled with issue of how to `remove` both key and (pointer object allocated by ***new*** operator) value? In case, if I used remove() method, would that be safe  in terms of memory release of dynamically allocated object?

Is this a good alternative?

```
myClass *type = types.take("foo");
delete type;
```

Comment: no that wont delete your instance of myClass and will result in a memory leak

Comment: You should use one of the Qt smart pointers, which will call `delete` for you. Every time it's needed, even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Qt documentation says about QMap::take() function

> Removes the item with the key key from the map and returns the value associated with it.

So that your code will remove the key from the map and delete the allocated memory for myClass object.

Comment: Key, as being stored as a value, will be destroyed as soon as the execution will go out of the scope.